# The Afterglow app won't recognize my controller

Tags: controllers

I recently got a wired Xbox One Afterglow controller. It worked fine until I plugged my headset in and it wouldn't let me change my headset settings. So I get the app and when I open it, it says that I'm not using an Afterglow controller, even though its the only thing plugged in.
Do I need to get a new one, or is it fixable?